# Reverse Proxy on IIS 8

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, windows-server-2012-r2, visualsvn-server

I have a windows 2012 web edition with IIS 8 installed, running several web applications and it must remain the main web server application.

One application, VisualSVN Server, running under Apache is running outside IIS, and I'd like to make it accessible also by a domain and not by the IP address on a different port than 80.

Therefore I need to create a proxy to redirect request coming for svn.mydomain.com to the local apache listening on port 8080.

I've tried to configure IIS to add a rule in the URL Rewrite section, but the Reverse Proxy is missing.

[image]

What I have to do to make it visible and add the reverse proxy rule?

Comment: You need to install ARR.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I have already installed using the "web platform installer 5.1". Currently the version 2.5 is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you may use the IIS manage console home's url rewrite rule not a specific web application inside the IIS.

Since the IIS manage console home's url rewrite rule is used to generate the global url rewrite rule not a url rewrite rule for a specific web application, it doesn't contain the  reverse proxy rule.

I suggest you could click the default web application and click its url rewrite icon, you will find it contains the reverse proxy.

More details, you could refer to below image:

[image]

The specific web application url rewrite rule:

[image]